this.app.dispatch is not a function Error In Shopify Embedded App
Can anybody please help.
I created an app in shopify via the Shopify cli with remix. On one of the ResourceItem that displays a product, I'm capturing the onClick event and trying to redirect to the admin product page. I used Redirect from @shopify/app-bridge-react to handle the redirection but still get the "this.app.dispatch is not a function" error
here's code:
import { useAppBridge } from "@shopify/app-bridge-react";
import { Redirect } from "@shopify/app-bridge/actions";

onClick={() => {
   // Create an App Bridge instance
   const app = useAppBridge();
   // Create a Redirect action
   const redirect = Redirect.create(app);
   redirect.dispatch(Redirect.Action.ADMIN_PATH,`/products/${productId}`);
}}


I also tried adding the config property to AppProvider from app.jsx but still did not work
<AppProvider
      isEmbeddedApp
      apiKey={apiKey}
      config={{
        apiKey: apiKey,
        shopOrigin: shopDomain,
        forceRedirect: true,
      }}
    >

